# How to output a .csv of my query records on my remote MySQL client?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, raspberry-pi

I am running a MySQL Client on a Raspberry Pi, and I am running the following query to retrieve the most recent records:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM my_table 
where '2017-01-19 09:00:00' > TS 
  and '2017-01-19 05:00:00' < TS 
order by TS desc 
limit 5000;
```

Since I am trying to write the output of the query to a file on my Raspberry Pi, I am running the following command from my terminal:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=my_username --password=my_password -e "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM db.my_table where '2017-01-19 09:00:00' > TS and '2017-01-19 05:00:00' < TS order by TS desc limit 5000;"> testcsv.csv
```

When I am looking at the host machine, it tells me that I am connected and the status is "Creating Sort Index".  I'll refresh the connections, and my connection no longer appears, and I run to check my Raspberry Pi to see if the command finished executing.  The command has not finished executing on my Raspberry Pi and nothing seems to happen.

Does anyone know what could be going on here?  Am I writing the file to my Raspberry Pi correctly?  The query is large, so could it be timing out?

EDIT:
I revised my Limit to 10, but I am receiving an error that `Identifier Name is too long`.  What is my identifier name?

Answer (score 1):

First, did you try to set the query to a more manageable size, say LIMIT 10 instead of LIMIT 5000, to see if it works? Secondly, looking at your query, should it be FROM database.my_table than FROM my_table? Other than that your query looks okay.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I will give it a go with a smaller limit.  And you're right about my FROM - I was using `FROM database.my_table`, I just did a typo when I was putting it into here.

Comment: I'm receiving `Identifier name is too long` error.  Have you ever seen that before?  Do you know what the identifier name is?

Comment: Take a look at this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html, does your table happened to have any field with name longer than 64 characters?